# YouTube gdata API for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

Can I use Java YouTube data API jar for developing YouTube Application in Android

I tried integrating the jar.
But when I run it is showing Exception

```
class def not found for YouTubeService
```

Sometimes it shows

```
class def not found for MediaSource
```

This is the sample program that I tested. I want to print the size of the list obtained after the query.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    service = new YouTubeService("myService");
    urlString = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated";
    try {
        videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(urlString), VideoFeed.class);
        videoEntries = videoFeed.getEntries();
        System.out.println("List Size"+videoEntries.size());


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Now it is showing the following error.

```
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387): javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387): javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:84)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:682)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:576)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:867)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2165)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.mcet.youtube.YoutubeActivity.onCreate(YoutubeActivity.java:38)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-03 16:27:38.844: WARN/XmlParser(387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 16:27:38.997: WARN/System.err(387): com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
09-03 16:27:39.005: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:708)
09-03 16:27:39.005: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:576)
09-03 16:27:39.005: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.data.BaseFeed.parseAtom(BaseFeed.java:867)
09-03 16:27:39.005: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:68)
09-03 16:27:39.014: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDataParser.parse(AtomDataParser.java:39)
09-03 16:27:39.014: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.CharacterParser.parse(CharacterParser.java:100)
09-03 16:27:39.014: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.XmlInputParser.parse(XmlInputParser.java:52)
09-03 16:27:39.025: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:66)
09-03 16:27:39.025: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.wireformats.input.AtomDualParser.parse(AtomDualParser.java:34)
09-03 16:27:39.025: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2165)
09-03 16:27:39.035: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
09-03 16:27:39.035: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
09-03 16:27:39.035: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
09-03 16:27:39.044: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
09-03 16:27:39.044: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
09-03 16:27:39.044: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.mcet.youtube.YoutubeActivity.onCreate(YoutubeActivity.java:38)
09-03 16:27:39.054: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-03 16:27:39.054: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-03 16:27:39.054: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-03 16:27:39.064: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-03 16:27:39.064: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-03 16:27:39.064: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 16:27:39.074: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-03 16:27:39.074: WARN/System.err(387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-03 16:27:39.074: WARN/System.err(387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 16:27:39.084: WARN/System.err(387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-03 16:27:39.084: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-03 16:27:39.084: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-03 16:27:39.084: WARN/System.err(387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 16:27:39.095: WARN/System.err(387): Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
09-03 16:27:39.095: WARN/System.err(387):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:84)
09-03 16:27:39.095: WARN/System.err(387):     at com.google.gdata.util.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:682)
09-03 16:27:39.095: WARN/System.err(387):     ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure (your question could be a little clearer?) but I think the problem you're having is that you need to Android port of JavaMail, which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list). Replace your existing mail.jar and activation.jar with the two found there, and add the additionnal.jar also. This should hopefully sort out your problem.

If not, please add your LogCat output and a bit more detail about the error and I'll try to help further.

Comment: after adding the jars , Class def not found is gone. Now It is not able to get the result. The logs are attached in the code.

Comment: @Abi Glad that worked for you. The exception you're getting is because the libraries you're using aren't full supported by Android. You may want to look at [this version](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) instead, which is apparently compatible with Android (I haven't tried it myself, but others have used it successfully).